# After merging code from Git having gradle build issue

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle

My application was running fine but after merging code from git i am facing this issue. After merging gradle build once but after that throwing this error in Message gradle build. I tried a lot but nothing worked for me.

> Error:In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute
>   android:fontVariationSettings
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>   process
>   C:\Users\sreekant\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe
>   with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I
>   C:\Users\sreekant\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar
>   -M \?\E:\Projects\boltt \app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S
>   E:\ Projects\boltt \app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J
>   \?\E:\ Projects\boltt \app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F E:\
>   Projects\boltt\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_
>   -D \?\E:\Projects\boltt\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\manifest_keep.txt
>   --custom-package com.boltt.health -0 apk --output-text-symbols \?\E:\ Projects\boltt\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
>   --no-version-vectors}

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    } } apply plugin: 'com.android.application' apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.boltt.health"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 18
        versionName "0.6"
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                useProguard true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        } //            release { //                minifyEnabled false //                shrinkResources false //               
useProguard true //                proguardFiles
getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
// // //            }


    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


} repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } }

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

} configurations {
    compile5
    compile6 }



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' //    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    implementation 'com.minimize.library:seekbar-compat:0.2.5'
    implementation 'com.github.CardinalNow:Android-CircleProgressIndicator:v0.2'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.amarjain07:StickyScrollView:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    // retrofit, gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'

    /*this library is for drawer layout. Please refer to the
                            * library page at : https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer*/
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.0.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    /*using for banding view*/

    //    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.6.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.0'

    /*Using for Graph*/
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'

    //    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'

    /*generic uses*/

    //    implementation("com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2") {

    //        exclude module: 'shared'

    //    }

    //    compile5 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'

    //    compile6 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

    // implementation 'com.github.jorgecastilloprz:fabprogresscircle:1.01@aar'

    // For networking
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'

    // For Bluetooth

    //    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:0.2.0'
    implementation ':validicmobile-release@aar'

    // implementation ':validicmobile-debug@aar'

    // You'll need to change this to point to your own jar.

    // Download: http://developer.samsung.com/health
    implementation fileTree(include: 'samsung-digital-health-healthdata-1.2.1.jar', dir:
'../../../Common/libs')
    implementation files('libs/samsung-digital-health-healthdata-1.2.1.jar')

    //    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

    // for round corners progress bar see in training lap analysis class
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:smsverifycatcher:0.3.1'

    //    implementation 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.0.0'

    //for hash tags view
    implementation 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.clarifai.clarifai-api2:core:2.0.2'

    implementation 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v1.2'

    //    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.3.0'

    /*used by suren
                * horizontal scrollable calendar used in plan section*/
    implementation 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.1.7'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation files('libs/ute_sdk_v2.5.5.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ProtocolUtils.jar')
    implementation files('libs/greendao-2.1.0.jar')

    // Larva

    implementation files('libs/PGSDK_V2.1.jar')
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.tamir7.contacts:contacts:1.1.7'
    implementation 'io.ticofab.androidgpxparser:parser:1.1.0'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.1'
    implementation 'com.github.lespinsideg:SimplePanorama:0.3.1'
    implementation 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.3.0'

    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1' }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```